# Rails mutliple has_one relationships as a has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a scenario where I need to have multiple has_one relationships and be able to access them all at once through a relationship.

Currently I have an STI table, we'll call it Animals.
There are subclasses: Lion, Meerkat, Boar

And they all need to relate to multiple Group objects.
So a Lion can be in multiple groups, but a Group may only have one Lion related.

I want to limit and refer to specifically one Lion, Meerkat and Boar.
I've tried a simple bridge table, has_many :animals, through: :associated_animals. But there doesn't seem to be an easy way to pull out group.lion.  I've also tried doing multiple has_one :lion/:meerkat/:boar relationships, but there was no obvious way to do group.animals.

Is there an STI way to get this functionality through default rails associations or do I have to do a combination of both the has_one :lion and has_many :animals?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this: 
`app/models/animal.rb`

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  belongs_to :group                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

class Lion < Animal; end                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
class Meerkat < Animal; end
```

Of course you can split out the Lion and Meerkat classes to separate ruby files

`app/models/group.rb`

```
 class Group < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   has_many :animals                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   has_one :lion                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   has_one :meerkat                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 end
```

after you run your migrations your schema should look something like this:
`db/schema.rb`

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150309234835) do                                                                                                                                                                                    

  create_table "animals", force: :cascade do |t|                                                                                                                                                                                           
    t.string   "name"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    t.string   "type"                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    t.integer  "group_id"                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|                                                                                                                                                                                            
    t.string   "name"                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

end
```

Now you should be able to write queries using group:

```
g = Group.find(1)
g.animals
g.lion
Lion.first.group
Animal.last.group
```

Comment: I added the following.  'belongs_to :lion, polymorphic: true' and attached the type column to the group for all 3 types.  The part that is still not working is the has_many :animals.  It is looking for the group_id on the animals table, of which there is none.

Comment: Then why don't you add the group_id column to the animals table?

Comment: The animals can be in many groups, but a group can only have 1 of each type.  So putting the ID on that table wouldn't work.

Comment: Then you have to use a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship in both models - animals and groups http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: The has_and_belongs_to_many relationship wouldn't allow for validation of just having one Lion would it?